# array to 'item' index in foreach loop

Tags: php, arrays, xml, curl, xml-parsing

procedure in simple step " XML URl data retrieve using curl, got XML array 
     as result, then XML array to simple PHP array, got output as below.

```
 Array ( [channel] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( [title] => Mobile01 本站新聞 
 [link] => (link##) [description] => Mobile01 本站新聞 [pubDate] => Fri, 22 
 Sep 2017 09:58:02 +0800 [item] => Array ( [0] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( 
 [title] => HP Envy 13-ad050TX 輕薄、獨顯、長效續航力 [link] => (link##) 
 [pubDate] => Fri, 22 Sep 2017 09:52:41 +0800 [description] => 
 SimpleXMLElement Object ( ) [category] => HP ) [1] => SimpleXMLElement 
  Object ( [title] => 雙倍震撼 RealShow TWIN 高解析雙體藍牙喇叭 [link] => 
 (link##) [pubDate] => Fri, 22 Sep 2017 09:43:45 +0800 [description] => 
 SimpleXMLElement Object ( ) [category] => 行動影音 )
```

Now i want only "item" from array not channel ..and when i tried foreach loop i got channel not "item" using given below code.

```
$post="";
    $agent = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; 
     rv:1.8.1.1) 
    Gecko/20061204 Firefox/2.0.0.1';
    $url= "https://www.mobile01.com/rss/news.xml";
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $agent); 
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);         
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: 
    application/json'));
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); 
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);           
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post);  
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0); 
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);

    $result = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    $xml = new SimpleXMLElement($result);

    $array = array();
    foreach($xml  as $k => $v) {
     $array[$k] = $v;
     }

      $i=0;
     print_r($array);
     foreach ($array->item as $key=>$entry) {

     echo "title===>". $title =$entry['title'];
     echo "link===>".$link =$entry['link'];

     echo "title111===>".$title11 = $entry -> title;
     echo "description===>".$description = $entry -> description;
```

got error when tried this code with different aspect,

```
Fatal error: 
        require_once(): Failed opening required 'lib/class.XmlToArray.php' 
        (include_path='.:/usr/lib/php:/usr/local/lib/php')
```

procedure in simple step " XML URl data retrieve using curl, got XML array 
     as result, then XML array to simple PHP array, got output as below.procedure in simple step " XML URl data retrieve using curl, got XML array 
     as result, then XML array to simple PHP array, got output as below.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to include any other library and just stick to using SimpleXML.  Once you get the correct data back, you can process it like...

```
<?php 
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);

$post="";
$agent = 'spider';
$url= "https://www.mobile01.com/rss/news.xml";
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $agent);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);

$result = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
$xml = new SimpleXMLElement($result);

foreach ($xml->channel->item as $key=>$entry) {    
    echo "title=>".$entry -> title.PHP_EOL;
    echo "description=>".$entry -> description.PHP_EOL;
}
```